# Pythonic method for getting output of call, and applying function again on it

Tags: python

this seems fairly basic, but i've been reading through the docs for itertools and comprehensions for a while now, and can't seem to find anything that does this.

I have a function called `breakSingleChar` which brute forces a password character by character, and this is how I use it to break a password of lenght 32:

```
res = ""
for i in range(32):
  res = breakSingleChar(res)
```

This feels like it could easily be much cleaner and pythonic, but I really can't figure out how.
Using `itertools.repeat` I was able to come up with this:

```
for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 32):
   res = breakSingleChar(res)
```

Which is more or less the same.

I guess if I was really creative, I could use `reduce` but this  feeels like I would just be absusing it.

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

**EDIT**

I have been asked to show some code that is runnable. To start with I did not find that this would be necessary since the issue here is so simple.
My bruteforcing function that I am calling is quite long, and would probably add to confusion regarding this question, so I will show an toy example where the same issue persists.

So let's say we have a function that checks if a number n is prime, and returns n+1 if it is not, and n-1, if is is:

```
# if number is prime, increment by one, else decrement
def PrimeChecker(n):
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i==0:
            return n + 1 
        
    return  n - 1
```

We now want to start with a certain number, and apply this function n times on it, and each time applying the function on the output of the last call:

```
res = 1007

for i in range(10):
    res = PrimeChecker(res)

print(res)
```

A recursive function would be cool, but likely would not be more concise

Can this be done in a nice way, perhaps using a comprehension or a functools resource?

**EDIT 2**
There has come to be some discussion in the comments over the term `pythonic`.

Perhaps this is due to me not using that term correctly.
Instead I should probably specify that I wish to limit the size, and thus lines of my program, and am generally practicing on using comprehensions/functools more often.
I would like to see if this can be done in this case

Comment: Please show runnable code and explain why it doesn't work for you

Comment: `range` is a totally reasonable way to repeat an operation `N` times.

Comment: What exactly does `breakSingleChar` do, append a character to its argument and return the new longer string? If generating a new trailing character requires all preceding characters, I'm not sure there's much else you'd want to do.

Comment: You could consider a ´recursive` function rather than calling the function n times

Comment: fixed second code block. @0x5453 But how could I save the state of the result in range?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony how would that be more Pythonic?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with your code? This seems perfectly Pythonic.

Comment: MOstly just that I find that it takes up quite a bit of lines, while being very simple

Comment: Are lines a limited resource? Again, this is perfectly Pythonic.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony in keeping with the idiomatic way Python is written. Recursion is not often used in Python unless it makes expressing the algorithm much easier (e.g. recursing through a tree structure). You would never replace a for-loop like this with recursion.

Comment: "quite a bit of lines"... Are we talking about the same 3 lines? There's nothing wrong with a simple for loop with a body of 1 line. (And please don't make this recursive, as someone suggested.)

Comment: The only unpythonic things in your first code are defining `i` but never using it and the two-spaces indent.

Comment: @DarkKnight, in general most questions are lacking a [mre] indeed. However, in this case, I think the original question was quite clear and the added code only made the question less clear.

Comment: If you want a oneliner and don't count imports, you *could* do `reduce(lambda res, _: breakSingleChar(res), range(32), "")`, but that's not less code and not more pythonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) to call a function a given number of times recursively.

```
import functools
print(functools.reduce(lambda v, f: f(v), [PrimeChecker] * 10, res))
```

or

```
import functools
print(functools.reduce(lambda v, _: PrimeChecker(v), range(10), res))
```